# Circuit and components for DC Fan

Tags: dc, fan

How to make a basic DC fan circuit with an on/off switch (source from batteries). I will be more than happy if I have the schematic and the component needed.

Comment: What sort of fan? Fan as in toy fan? Fan as in 5V PC cooler. ...?

Answer (score 6):

These components will do the trick:

- 12V battery
- Push button switch
- 12V DC fan

Then you just connect them in series in whichever order you prefer, for instance:

[image]